# Numbers with (.0) decimals are considered integers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, integer, precision

I was working with some validation that it was supposed to allow integers only, I had something like this:

```js
let value = '32230.13';

if(!!Number.isInteger(+value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''))) {
  // stuff
}
```

Definitely not the most pretty way to do it but it was working fine for us until we got values ending on `.0`. So I noticed that values ending with `.0` are considered integers. Eg:

```js
console.log(Number.isInteger(100.0)) // expected `false` got `true`
console.log(Number.isInteger(100.00)) // expected `false` got `true`
```

So I started researching a little about integers, and I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56393941/7602110, but it made me think that it was some of those weird JavaScript issues that we have to deal with when working with Javascript (WTFJS). I even found something similar https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs and even went to try the same thing in different programming languages and I was getting the expected result that `100.0` was not an integer, but I still have some questions:

- Is 100.0 an integer?

  - If yes, is the Javascript method (`Number.isInteger`) wrong?

    - Should I open a pull request adding this to [wtfjs](https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs) (this one not important lol)?
- What can I do to actually ignore `.00` values to be considered integers.

Comment: Why do you believe, that `100.0` would not be an integer?

Comment: Numbers in JavaScript are always floating point, but it does a good job of pretending they aren't.

Comment: The `number` type in JavaScript is ***only*** a floating point number representation. There are not different integers when you have a JS numeric. Unless it's a BigInt but that's not what you have here. With that said, an integer is...a whole number. A number without a fractional part is a whole number. Why would it *not* be an integer? If you REALLY want to go mathematical about it, then yes - `100.0` is not an integer. But neither is *any other number* as they all come from the set of rational numbers, therefore are not integers. But for practical purposes the set also contains integers.

Comment: I wouldn't even agree there - mathematically, 100.0 is an integer.

Comment: @ASDFGerte in very strict mathematics, integers and rational/real numbers are different. Easy to show with `10 / 4` - if we're working within the integer set, then we need to get an integer result, which is `2`. If the result is `2.5`, then that's a rational number and we jumped between sets. Again, though, that's *very strict* mathematics. In most cases, we just implicitly convert to rationals as it's convenient. And in compsci, we're nothing but practical with the approach. Mathematicians wouldn't include zero in natural numbers but we start our counting there as it's convenient.

Comment: ℤ is not a field, and has no (common) division. There is however a trivial ring-monomorphism ℤ↪ℝ, and not identifying the real numbers inside its image as integers is imho not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript standard is actually very clear about the difference between "mathematical values" and `Numbers` as represented in the language (https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-mathematical-operations)

From the mathematical standpoint, `100.0` is definitely an integer. From the JS standpoint, `isInteger(100.0)` is `true`, because `isInteger` is defined to return `true` for `Numbers` whose mathematical value is integer.

Your uncertainty  comes from the fact in some other languages `100` and `100.0` are indeed quite different things, with different storage mechanisms and the nature of operations performed on them. In Javascript, we actually don't know how a particular number is stored, and have no control over that. The standard says that all `Numbers` should behave as if they all were IEEE 754-2019 double values, but what sequence of operations a particular engine actually performs when you compute `1+2` and how they are different from `1.2+3.4` is up to that engine.

Comment: How do you figure “what a particular engine actually does when you compute `1+2` is up to that engine”? JavaScript implements ECMAScript, and ECMAScript is specific about this. Per the ECMAScript 2020 Language Specification 6.1.6.1.7, “The **+** operator performs addition… The result of an addition is determined using the rules of IEEE 754-2019 binary double precision arithmetic… the sum is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2019 roundTiesToEven mode…” Or do you mean the resulting value is known but the method of computation is unknown?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes, the latter. Internally "1+2" is handled differently from "1.2+3.4"  (in v8 at least)  Clarified that in the post.